# Is this TV power supply board damaged?

Tags: power-supply, repair, surge-protection, tv

A suspected power surge killed our TV (Mitsubishi WD-65738 DLP) the other night. Upon looking up the error code "48", I ended up buying and replacing the main board "PWB-MAIN".

While this didn't seem to fix the issue, there's a new problem:
**Upon plugging in the TV, a rapid internal clicking is heard - the normal type of "click" signifying power is restored. However, it's rapidly going on and off while the green LED on the front flashes with it.**

In my limited experience (*read: none*) this doesn't seem normal or like it's trying to "tell" me something but rather is shorting itself out over and over. Either I screwed something up or there's another issue (maybe PWB-MAIN wasn't even bad?).

Either way, I dare not plug the TV back in, but I am curious about the power-supply board, here is a picture of it.

[image]
Are those two big capacitors bad? They look "buldgy". Is it worth replacing this $20 board too?

Originally I thought all that white gunk leaking out of the capacitor was bad, but even images of new boards seem to have it.
[image: new PCB detail]

Comment: Bad caps may causing short circuit and therefore, auto-shutdown perhaps.

Answer (score 9):

Those two main filter caps definitely look bad, as though the electrolyte has boiled away. I'd try replacing them next.

Comment: The cracked "vent" lines on the top of them, with brownish goo coming out, are definitely "vented" capacitors. Now whether they failed slowly in normal service or rapidly as the surge happened, is undetermined. But those are definitely bad, and who knows what else. For simplicity, a $20 replacement board sounds like the easiest and cheapest bet.

Comment: +1 Yes, the caps are bad! Bulged and vent open. That could cause the symptoms OP describes.